# Import CSV file into Sqlite3 Database in command-line or via Batch File

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, import, sqlite

I would like to inquire on whether is there anyway to import a csv file that contains output of my select statements in SQLite3 into a new database?
Following are the codes i have done thus far:

```
sqlite3.exe -csv logsql.sqlite "SELECT local_port AS port, COUNT(local_port) AS hitcount FROM connections  WHERE connection_type = 'accept' GROUP BY local_port ORDER BY hitcount DESC;" > output.csv
sqlite3.exe -csv test.sqlite "CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(255) not null, blah varchar(255) not null);" .import ./output.csv test
```

as you can see my first code was to dump out the queries made.

the second line of code i'm attempting to make a new database and attemptign to import the csv file into the table "test"

thanks for any help made in advance! :D

Comment: The big question I need to ask here is: why do you need to do this? Is it a one-time operation, is this part of a program?

Comment: yes this is part of a program. i intend to run the batch script to generate my own table to reduce the processing time for graphical presentation in my php program

Answer (score 15):

I'd recommend doing your importation from a flat file, which will create your schema followed with the actual importation:

Like so:

```
sqlite3.exe test.sqlite < import.sql
```

Where the content of import.sql is:

```
CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(255) not null, blah varchar(255) not null);
.separator ,
.import output.csv test
```

One other approach which you might not have considered is the [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command. You can attach a new database, create the table in it, and import to its table, so you don't have the extra step of exporting to CSV then reparsing. It can be from a [CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) query or just an INSERT.

So basically, you'd run (from your PHP Page):

```
"ATTACH 'c:\directory\to\database\test.db' as TESTDB;"
"CREATE TABLE TESTDB.test AS SELECT local_port AS port, COUNT(local_port) AS hitcount FROM connections  WHERE connection_type = 'accept' GROUP BY local_port ORDER BY hitcount DESC;"
```

Or:

```
"ATTACH 'c:\directory\to\database\test.db' as TESTDB;"
"CREATE TABLE TESTDB.test (name varchar(255) not null, blah varchar(255) not null);"
"IMPORT INTO TESTDB.test SELECT local_port AS port, COUNT(local_port) AS hitcount FROM connections  WHERE connection_type = 'accept' GROUP BY local_port ORDER BY hitcount DESC;"
```

Comment: i'm sorry i don't quite understand your first paragraph. as i'm using batch script. i'm unable to use the DOT commands?

Comment: thank you very much for the prompt response. They came back with an error saying Error: expected 2 columns of data but found 1. Is it because my 1st code generates only one column? I have opened the csv file and noticed 2 columns filled.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that .import and -csv create different separators. Please see my edits.

Comment: I can't seem to run a script from a file against a sqlite3 database in this way - it complains `Error: incomplete SQL:     .separator ,
    .import output.csv items`

Comment: @MichaelForrest `items` is not an SQL command. If you need further help, you'd better start a new question.

Comment: `items` is the equivalent of 'test' in the command discussed (as in `.import output.csv test` - it's an argument for the `.import`. I think this is valid commentary for this question.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just missing a trailing line break.

Comment: No it was because everything in the file was indented when I generated the script from Ruby! Ok never mind.

Answer (score 9):

A single-file command to import a file via bash that worked for me:

```
sqlite3 inventory.sqlite.db << EOF
delete from audit;
.separator "\t"
.import audit-sorted-uniq.tsv audit
EOF
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way I find is to make sure that in the csv file the first row are the name of the columns and the values starts from row 2.

```
sqlite3 database.db ".import --csv /user/name/work/somedata.csv tab1"
```

- Where database is the database where the table will be created.
- schema will be create based on the values of the first row as the name of the columns.
- /user/name/... is the path for the csv file ( Linux file system )
- tab1 is the name of the table being created.

Answer (score 1):

For large CSV files it may be more efficient to use the `sqlite3` shell's `.import` command, rather than parse the file in Python and insert rows with `sqlite3` module. It can be done via `os.system` (on Linux, Unix or Mac OS X, or Cygwin on Windows):

```
cmd = '(echo .separator ,; echo .import ' + csv_file + ' ' + table + ')'
cmd += '| sqlite3 ' + db_name
os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with the SQLite command shell and command-line switches...
... but I'd strongly urge you to find a SQLite-aware scripting language that'll work on Windows and that you feel comfortable with.

Perl and Python are two excellent choices.  Both support SqlLite, both are freely available for Windows.

And both can handle this - and many other kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need correct real csv file with comma separator and header line. 
I used the dump tool from phpstorm for this.

put all files into a folder.

**open cmd.exe**

**create import statements where %~na is the filename without extension as tablename**

```
for /R %a in (*.csv) do @echo .import %~na.csv %~na >> import.txt
```

**start sqlite with a dummy db**

```
sqlite test.sqlite
```

**set import mode to csv**

```
.mode csv
```

**run commands from file**

```
.read import.txt
```

**list all tables**

```
.tables
```

**quit sqlite**

```
.q
```

Answer (score -1):

I nedded to import many csv files, so I wrote the following python script that does the job of creating and loading sqlite tables from csv files, using the first line of the csv as the field names for the table:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3
from csv import DictReader

class SQLiteDB():
    def __init__(self, dbname=':memory:'):
        self.db=sqlite3.connect(dbname)

    def importFromCSV(self, csvfilename, tablename, separator=","):
        with open(csvfilename, 'r') as fh:
            dr = DictReader(fh, delimiter=separator)
            fieldlist=",".join(dr.fieldnames)
            ph=("?,"*len(dr.fieldnames))[:-1]
            self.db.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s"%tablename)
            self.db.execute("CREATE TABLE %s(%s)"%(tablename, fieldlist))
            ins="insert into %s (%s) values (%s)"%(tablename, fieldlist, ph)
            for line in dr:
                v=[]
                for k in dr.fieldnames: v.append(line[k])
                self.db.execute(ins, v)
        self.db.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db=SQLiteDB("mydatabase.sqlite")
    db.importFromCSV("mydata.csv", "mytable")
```

For importing a large amount of data, you should implement transactions.

hth